# Send API response in AWS after that, run process in background (async)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await, aws-api-gateway

I do have an endpoint DELETE book/{bookname}. When user request to endpoint, he/she have to get response "This book will be deleted after 10 minute". And after sending response, another function will start and delete book from database after 10 minutes. **I have to use async** only and Python 3.7. I have succeeded, all of them works fine ,except sending response to user. 
Now, User sends request to DELETE /book/{bookname} and waits... (background processes will delete after 10 minutes) . after some seconds due to timeout, user receives "Request Timeout". I just want to send  success message to user (it does not matter book will be deleted or not) and run processes background in AWS Lambda. (I must not use invoke and stepfunctions)

Comment: Aws lambda destinations may help for your case. please check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

Edit: If i understand it correctly; api gateway async integration may solve it instead of destinations. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html

Comment: As an option, lambda can submit job to SQS delay queue with delay set to 10 mins, and just respond to client